# Difference Between PAT with pool or Interface/Loopback?

Tags: nat, cisco-ios

I'm just wondering what difference does it make when doing PAT with same IP defined in pool or assigning IP on Loopback and overloading that interface.

```
ip nat pool MYPOOL 1.1.1.1 1.1.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.252  
ip nat inside source list 1 POOL MYPOOL overload

interace loopback 103
  ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255  
ip nat inside source list 1 interface loopback103 overload
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the pool if you have multiple global addresses to use for source addresses.

You can use the loopback if it is a global address. That can be useful if you have multiple WAN routers, and you may have asymmetric routing. If the return traffic comes back to the wrong router, and the wrong router has a route back to the loopback address, then if you have the interface on the correct router from the wrong router set as an outside interface, then you can get the return traffic correctly translated back.

Generally,, asymmetric routing with NAPT can be a problem because if you use a pool, if the traffic comes back to the wrong router, the return traffic will not get translated correctly, and the return traffic will get dropped. Routers do not share NAT tables.

What to use, and how you use it, depends on the particular topology and needs.

Comment: Something is not clear for me. Is there a proper way to do asymmetric routing with NAPT with a pool or we should always use only one global IP in this specific case? Isn't it possible for the second router to add a static route to the whole pool of the first router instead of just to the loopback IP?